# ARIMA - GARCH or AR-GARCH

Tags: arima, autoregressive, garch, differencing

I am looking at equity returns and they are not stationary at level. So i take the 1st difference to make them stationary.

My GARCH(1,1) model is modeled using an AR(1) parsimonious model. But, since I've taken the first difference in the equity return series, does that indicate it's an ARIMA(1,1,0) model rather than an AR(1) model?

I'm perplexed since I've read papers that use the first difference of their return series to model their GARCH, yet they claim to employ an AR(1)-GARCH model rather than an ARIMA(1,1,0)-garch model in their methodology section.

if i take the first difference, don't I have to include the d in the the ARIMA(p,d,q) model? Why is it being referred to as an AR(1) in the papers?.
The fact that it is abbreviated as an AR(1) may lead readers to believe that the return series are stationary at level, which is not the case.

Or am I mistaken in assuming it's an ARIMA(1,1,0)-GARCH model rather than an AR(1)-GARCH model?

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking at equity returns and they are not stationary at level. So i take the 1st difference to make them stationary.

Differencing is a valid remedy for a specific form of nonstationarity, namely, a unit root. Presence of a unit root in equity returns would imply a great degree of predictability, and that is empirically not the case. Hence, differencing the returns is unjustified. (I am talking about log-returns $r_t:=\log\big(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}\big)$ or percentage returns $\tilde r_t:=\frac{P_t-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$. If your notion of *return* is very different from that, consider stating it explicitly.)

> I've read papers that use the first difference of their return series

Could you give any references? I have never seen such a paper.

> The fact that it is abbreviated as an AR(1) may lead readers to believe that the return series are stationary at level, which is not the case.

AR(1) with a small autoregressive coefficient is much closer to the empirical reality of $r_t$ than ARIMA(1,1,0). Even so AR(1) implies predictability and thus is problematic, but much less so than ARIMA(1,1,0).

Comment: Yes my return series have unit root, which is why i take the 1st difference, to get rid of unit root. My series is also on log format for better interpretation.

Comment: I follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61W9FrWDQEE&list=PLsZ8kVwX52ZGXxJ-bqP-WmRBD2HytO4d4

Comment: He does the same, he uses the log and differences series of the return. But calls it an ARMA instead of ARIMA for the mean equation. But isn't it an ARIMA since he takes the first difference?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to watch the entire video. If you wrote down its main points, we could discuss them. If you insist on your time series having a unit root, I bet it is a series of prices or their logarithms rather than returns. That may be the key to solving your puzzle.

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right my series is of equity prices and so is the series in the video. starts at 5:40min. The guy in the video says that, to look at the returns of the series he must change the series to log and differences. He then looks at the correlogram to determine the mean equation (the AR and MA component). He wants to use parsimonious model so he keeps it simple and decides to use ARMA(1,1) model. My question now is, since the return series is in first differences of the price series, isn't the mean equation an ARIMA(1,1,1) instead of ARMA(1,1)? or am i confusing things up.

Comment: @coolkid9090, there does not seem to be a mistake in the video. An ARIMA(1,0,1) for the log-returns is the same as an ARIMA(1,1,1) for log-prices. The log-returns are not differenced anymore because they are themselves the first difference of log-prices.

Comment: @coolkid9090, have you figured this out, or do you need additional assistance? (I see you have neither upvoted nor accepted my answer.)